# In Spring Batch how to configure tasklet steps as .faultTolerant for DeadlockLoserDataAccessException

Tags: spring-batch

I have following steps which call the Tasklet - is it possible to configure it as fault-tolerant - I need it to handle DeadlockLoserDataAccessException, the following code gives the compilation error -

Step testCostDataStep = stepBuilderFactory.get(JobConstants.UPSERT_STEP)
                 .tasklet(upsertCostData())
                 .listener(steplistener)
                 .faultTolerant()
                 .retryLimit(5)
                 .retry(DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class)
                 .build();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have following steps which call the Tasklet - is it possible to configure it as fault-tolerant

No, fault tolerance features (skip/retry) are only available for chunk-oriented steps. For a tasklet, you can catch the exception in your tasklet code and act accordingly.

Comment: Tasklet is calling service class method so, I have annotated service method with - @Retryable(value = { DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class }, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000))  and its working as expected.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you fixed your issue.